# How can I exclude a string anyhwere in the pattern from matches?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3, url, query-string

I need to write a regex which will match URLs that do **not** have a specific query string name/value pair **anywhere** in its URL.  All other query string names, and all other query string values with the same name should be matched.  Other pages in the same directory (or sub-directories) should not be matched.

For example, suppose the base URL that I need to match is:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/
```

The query string name and value that I need to exclude from matches is:

```
fred=f
```

So far, I’ve got:

```
http://www\.domain\.com/directory/(?!(\?|&)fred=f$)
```

Which matches:

- http://www.domain.com/directory/
- http://www.domain.com/directory/?fred=a
- http://www.domain.com/directory/?fred=foo

But not:

- http://www.domain.com/directory/?fred=f

The problem is that this regex also matches:

- http://www.domain.com/directory/?foo=bar&fred=f

If I use this regex instead:

```
(?i)http://www\.domain\.com/directory/[a-z]*(?!(\?|&)fred=f$)
```

Then this URL is matched:

- http://www.domain.com/directory/foobar?fred=f

(It seems that the [a-z] is stronger than the disallow group.)

How can I prevent matches when the string exists anywhere in the pattern?

(This will be used in an ActionScript3/ECMAScript3 regex engine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my colleagues provided the basis for this answer:

```
http://www.domain.com/directory/(?!.*(\?|&)fred=f($|&|#))(\?|#|$)
```

This regex matches:

- `http://www.domain.com/directory/`
- `http://www.domain.com/directory/?fred=a`
- `http://www.domain.com/directory/?fred=foo`
- `http://www.domain.com/directory/?foo=bar`

but not:

- `http://www.domain.com/directory/?fred=f`
- `http://www.domain.com/directory/?fred=f&a=b`
- `http://www.domain.com/directory/?a=b&fred=f`

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you need to use a regex? Why not just a simple string search? It does exactly the same thing, buts easier to understand.

```
myString.search("fred=f");
```

Tyler.

Comment: I am working within a platform that accepts URLs, or regular expressions to match URLs against, to determine whether or not to do stuff. It would take quite a bit of work to implement a deeper logic.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Changed the expression. Previous version was limited to **99** characters.

EDIT2: Improved the expression, now matches more cases.

I have made something like this

```
(domain.com/directory/.*fred=(?!f$)(?!f&).*)|(domain.com/directory/$)|(domain.com/directory/\?(?!.*fred=f).*)
```

and tested it on the following strings

1. **domain.com/directory/?foo=f&bar=f**
2. **domain.com/directory/?foo=bar**
3. **domain.com/directory/?aaa=bar**
4. **domain.com/directory/**
5. **domain.com/directory/?fred=a**
6. **domain.com/directory/?fred=foo**
7. **domain.com/directory/?foo=bar&fred=foo**
8. domain.com/directory/?fred=f&aaaw=bbb
9. domain.com/directory/?fred=f
10. domain.com/directory/?foo=bar&fred=f

My regexp matched the ones in bold. 
I have tested it at [www.RegexTester.com](http://www.regextester.com/)

Comment: The second regex works pretty well, but what does {2,99} do?  Would it only match up to 100 characters in some substring?

Comment: I have edited my post. Now, the regexp works exactly as you would like it do work.

Comment: Thanks for your effort on this.  Unfortunately the query string (http://www.domain.com/directory/.*fred=(?!f$)(?!f&).*)|(http://www.domain.com/directory/$) doesn't work as I expect it to because it doesn't match other query strings, such as http://www.domain.com/directory/?foo=bar.

Comment: When my answer will match your request I suggest removing the  unnecessary comments.